# A unique ID for an app

Tags: objective-c

I know this question was asked before , but i found that there are some unclear/unsoved issues about it,and some updates, and i wanted to make order for me and for others .

As one need to have a unique id for each app, so the server can identify it, we used to have the `UDID` which is now `deprecate` .

I have found 4 other ways to do that, but there are some issues about them and we dont want to take a risk .

1. `NSString *UD= [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString ;`

I have read here that sometimes you can get 0000.. when creating this number- because apple has some bug for people who where update ios on air . (apple confirmed that )
Another thing - there is the `advertisingIdentifier`- is it better ?

2.

```
CFUUIDRef uuidObject = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString *uuidStr = ( NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject);
```

This way Do create a unique id , and i can than save it to `NSUserDefaults` and use it.
But ,if one's erase his app, we have a problem. also, i have heard this one has also some issues with other iOS under 6 ?

3
 `MAC adress` with third-party classes,  which i have read-also has ios compatibility issues,

So at the bottom line , is there a common way to get an id which is working always for every ios ?

Comment: You are probably talking about device IDs, enabling you to identify individual users of your app. The way you put it sounds like you are looking for an ID that identifies your app (like the iTunes.connect ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok After so much research i think i found some combination that gives the best way to do this.
Correct me if i am wrong .

Using method 2 , create a uniqueID with the `CFUUIDRef` is great , but you cant save it to `NSUserdefaults` because uninstall will erase it !

So , we can save it to the keychain ,and have it there forever ,something like :

```
SFHFKeychainUtils storeUserName: andPassword: forServiceName:
```